# Sharing a database between website and desktop application

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, iis

I have a small intranet ASP.NET website that uses a SQL Server database accessed via entity framework. I've been asked to create a small desktop application (exe) that accesses the same database. Whats the best way to share the database between these two application types? I dont want to have to have two separate EDMX's as any changes to the database need to be reflected in both code bases.

Can I create a 3rd project to hold the database connection stuff and then share this project in the desktop application and the web application? Is this the best practice?

Comment: Put the EDMX in it's own project and reference it from web and app.

Comment: Thought that was the case, but I just wanted a sanity check

Comment: in your web app you should have a domain dll and a DAL dll. You can use these dlls in your desktop app. If you have not such dll, refactor your web app to produce them. At a project level you MUST (imho) share dll, not database. So yes, the best practice is the 3rd project way.

Comment: Thanks guys, does it matter what sort of project it is?

Comment: yes, a library project. Said project will be referenced in 2 others.

Comment: Class Library, got it, thanks for your help